# Angular routing - Prefix route when navigating

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm using module federation with Angular.
In my remote app I would like to prefix my routes with a key without modifying my routing files.

I've tried to set it globally but it doesn't work :

**app.routing.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'mfe1',
    loadChildren: () => import('core.module').then((m) => m.CoreModule),
},
{ path: '**', loadComponent: () => import('./error').then((m) => m.ErrorComponent) },
];

@NgModule({
declarations: [],
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
        enableTracing: true
    }),
],
})
export class AppRouting {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
  { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/mfe1'}
```

When I try :

```
router.createUrlTree(['/route1'])
// or
router.navigate(['/route1'])
```

In my Browser, url has changed to :

`localhost:4200/#/mfe1/route1`

But router tracing outputs :

```
NavigationEnd {id: 2, url: '/route1', urlAfterRedirects: 'route1', type: 1}
```

'mfe1' has not been prefixed during navigation.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong ? Or another way to do that ?